Neural network always predicts the same value
My neural network always predicts the same value, the problem arises when I try to normalize the target value, if I don't it works fine. Does anyone have an idea of why?
def create_and_train_model_opti2(dff, target_column):
    df = dff.copy()
    
    
    y = df[target_column].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    X = df.drop([target_column], axis=1)
    #X = X.drop(['cmf_pos'], axis=1).values  
    
    # Normalize features
    scaler_X = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    X_scaled = scaler_X.fit_transform(X)
    
    # Normalize the target
    scaler_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    y_scaled = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)
    
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y_scaled, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    
    
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
        Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)),
        Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(1)
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error')
    
    
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=60, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2)
    
    return model, history, y_train, y_test, X_train, X_test, scaler_y

def make_and_view_predictions(model, X_test, y_test, scaler_y):
    
    y_pred_scaled = model.predict(X_test)
    
    # Inverse  predictions
    y_pred = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_pred_scaled)
    
    # Inverse transform the actual test 
    y_test_original = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_test)
    
    
    for i in range(len(y_test)):
        print(f"Predicted: {y_pred[i][0]:.2f}, Actual: {y_test_original[i][0]:.2f}")
    
    return y_pred, y_test_original

This is the output that I have:
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 156.80
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 193.57
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 34.67
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 281.60
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 0.00
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 558.53
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 21.41
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 0.00
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 560.24
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 311.48
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 135.14
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 0.00
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 403.05
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 0.00
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 46.62
Predicted: 353.50, Actual: 2579.44

I tried to search the libraries but nothing works

Impossible to say exactly what happened without seeing the weights of your model. Most likely it didn't learn anything e.g. didn't change its weights. Try increasing (or decreasing) the learning rate, adding more epochs, removing regularization. Your data might also be heavily skewed or have outliers that make it difficult to learn, especially after normalizing.
